# Banner do AdMob no Ionic não aparece mais quando coloco o Id gerado pelo site

Tags: ionic, admob

O banner do adMob no ionic quando o 'id' está vazio está funcionando, mas quando coloco o 'id' fornecido no site do adMob ele não aparece mais, alguém poderia me ajudar nesse problema?

```
 const bannerConfig:AdMobFreeBannerConfig={
    id:'ca-app-pub-4354735883939440/9861159567',
    autoShow:true,
    isTesting:false,
    bannerAtTop: false,
    overlap: true,

  }
  this.adMob.banner.config(bannerConfig);
  this.adMob.banner.prepare().then(() =>{

  } )
  .catch(e => console.log(e));
```

Answer (score 0):

Amigo, agora só aparece quando vc assina o apk, ou seja, fique tranquilo que quando vc publicar o banner vai aparecer, tive o mesmo problema.

Comment: já publiquei e assinei, mas ainda não apareceu o banner

Comment: cola aqui o seu código de admob que te ajudo.